# scatterplot with equal axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set like this one below:

```
DataFrame <- data.frame(x=runif(25),y=runif(25),
                        z=sample(letters[1:4],25,rep=TRUE))
```

and using the Lattice package, I can make a scatter plot with equal axes (with a 1:1 line going through the centre) with the following lines:

```
xyplot(y ~ x | z, data=DataFrame,
       scales=list(relation="free"),
       prepanel=function(x,y,...) {
         rg <- range(na.omit(c(x,y)))
         list(xlim=rg,ylim=rg)
       },panel=function(x,y,...) {
         panel.abline(0,1)
         panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
       })
```

In ggplot2, I have gotten this far:

```
ggplot(data=DataFrame) + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  facet_grid(~z,scales="free") + coord_equal(ratio=1) +
  geom_abline(intercept=0,slope=1)
```

But I'm not sure that coord_equal() is the function I'm looking for. What might be the equivalent function call in ggplot2?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem lies in setting free facet scales. Once you set the facet scales to be free, you can't then add `coord_equal()` If you eliminate the free scales, then `coord_equal()` works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `facet_wrap()` is a better choice, and as far as I know the control of `xlim` and `ylim` for individual panels is not available in **ggplot2**.

Comment: If you need that kind of control on each panel, then you technically aren't faceting anymore, which by definition is designed for common axes. Instead, you might try looking at something like `grid.arrange` in the **gridExtra** package.