# Splitting ggplot plot map into 3 frames

Tags: r, split, ggplot2

Is it possible to extract specific sections of a ggplot figure/map and place them side by side in a secondary figure but still add points to the three frames as if they were still one plot i.e. for the following map

[image]

create a map split into 3 sections which can then be manipulated as one graph (i.e. adding points to all three sections of the graph simultaneously?

[image]

UPDATE: Reproducible example

```
set.seed(1)
dfx<-c(sample(1:1000,100),sample(2000:3000,100),sample(4000:3000,100))
dfy<-c(sample(1:1000,100),sample(2000:3000,100),sample(4000:3000,100))

p<-ggplot()+
coord_fixed()+
geom_point(aes(x=dfx,y=dfy))
p
```

[image]

Comment: Added a reproducible example to the original question....any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I can get partway there but can't retain the effects of `coord_equal` or `coord_fixed` while allowing free scales ... hopefully someone else can step in and get the rest of the way.  (This has come up before -- [scatterplot with equal axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564044/scatterplot-with-equal-axes) -- but I haven't seen a solution.)

```
dd <- data.frame(dfx,dfy)
dd2 <- transform(dd,panel=cut(dfx,seq(0,4000,by=1000),labels=1:4))
p <- ggplot(dd2)+geom_point(aes(dfx,dfy)) + coord_equal()
p + facet_wrap(~panel,nrow=1,scale="free")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for having a look